ECS Fargate Tasks Stopping Randomly and Concurrently
I am experiencing an issue with one of my services where the health check response time becomes problematic after a period of operation. Initially, when I start the service, it responds correctly and health checks pass. However, after some time—whether it's one day, two days, or even 4 to 5 hours—the health checks start timing out, and the tasks begin draining. This indicates that the service takes too long to respond after being operational for some time.
I have two target group connected with one task as task is working on two port and two domain.
task is draining due to two issues as follow:

unhealthy in target-group due to (reason Request timed out).
**The task exited with exit code 137. **

"stoppedReason": "Essential container in task exited",
"stopCode": "EssentialContainerExited",
"exitCode": 0


Despite increasing the Unhealthy threshold value from 2 to 3, the servers start draining after some time, resulting in slow responses from the ECS services. Why is this happening? how do I resolve this issue?
one more thing I have started ecs service using aws cli as the application is working on two different port and domain.

You say the health checks start timing out, and that is why the tasks are stopped, but the log messages in your question state that the containers exited unexpectedly (crashed), and that is the reason they are being stopped. You need to verify if the software in your containers is crashing, and possibly add more logging to determine that.

@MarkB Thanks for the call out - Odd as there's an edit to that comment that is missing (after I clicked on the wrong duplicate) - I'll delete it. However, 137 in most contexts means OOM, the duplicate was intended to point the OP in this direction.

@AD7six good call on the OOM, that's probably the issue, since it sounds like the container itself is crashing for some reason.

Please share the task definition. It appears that your fargate task has insufficient memory allocated.
